# htmlentites use str_replace for img exception output empty string

Tags: php

```
$output = htmlentities($output, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
$output = str_replace("&lt;img","<img",$output);
```

I have a data contain text and image inside of my db,

I need to output it with htmlentites with exception

I tried to use str_replace, somehow, it return empty string after

anyone know where is the problem

Comment: what does the $output contain before and after above codes? the codes you provided are perfectly fine and shouldn't return empty unless the $output itself was provided empty.

Comment: like this <img class='img-left' src='https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/ac/ad/62/acad62e1e47531a58160c8f4a775d3e5.jpg' />

Comment: then it outputs <img class='img-left' src='s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/ac/ad/62/&hellip;; /&gt; which is not empty.

Comment: idk why, i got empty string

Comment: your code is not sufficient to debug exact cause. check this: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d1fdc23bbd8e18d12127026049321f513afe9de0